# How are timeouts represented in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timing, v8, internal-representation

When I call set timeout it returns a number, for example

```
> setTimeout(function(){ console.log('done'); },1000);
4431
"done"
```

I know that I can use this number to call `clearTimeout()` but what does this number represent internally?

Comment: Another oddity: on some browsers (Chrome at least) you can clear interval timers ("setInterval()") with "clearTimeout()".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter what it represents. It could be an address in memory, or an index into an array, or the National ID # of the programmer who wrote the interpreter + offset.

You don't care. You *better not care*. Whatever it corresponds to today, internally on one particular browser / JS environment, it could well mean something else tomorrow somewhere else.

All you need to know is that this number corresponds to your timer. If you need to do something to your timer later on, you'll want that number, so keep it safe. When the timer is dead, throw it away and never think of it again.

---

If you're interested in some slightly-gritty details, see [the spec for the list of active timeouts](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#list-of-active-timeouts) - there's no requirement that the number (the handle) represents *anything* internally, merely that it can be used to reliably identify a specific timer.

If you're interested in some *really* gritty details, download the source for [your favorite browser](http://www.webkit.org/building/checkout.html) and go to town...

Comment: otherwise known as an "opaque handle"

Comment: @Thomas that's why we're here... :)

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say but this is more about satisfying my own curiosity than solving a programming problem.

Comment: @Alnitak you can say that again! :) I've learned so much in the 2.5 months i've been here.

Comment: @Greg: I've added a reference - but I suspect you're missing the point. The number doesn't *have* to represent anything internally beyond what it represents externally.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the JS engine used, hence on the browser used. I know from older questions that each browsers uses a different way of enumerating the returned IDs.

Answer (score 0):

It is the id representing the way to track the the event.

Answer (score -1):

I think the usual way to do this is to set a variable equal to the setTimeout statement, such as myTO = setTimeout(...) then you clear it with clearTimeout(myTO).

Comment: this does not answer the question: "what does this number represent internally?"